# Masonry container with fluid margins in em

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I am trying to make my jQuery Masonry wall the same width as the header just above it on a pseudo-fluid layout. See http://blart-philip.com

I can't find a way.

My CSS code `width: 51em;` gets overriden by the masonry JS at the element level, making it always relative to the `article#content` container.

What can be done?

Here is my JS code:

```
// remap jQuery to $
(function($){})(window.jQuery);

/* Masonery for the index page */

var $container = $('.wall');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.brique',
    columnWidth : 150,
    isAnimated: true,
    isFitWidth: true
  });

});
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Pat

Comment: Your remap code does nothing, FYI

Answer (score 0):

The width of each element must be a multiple of the wall and the header if it is the same width. This is the meaning of columnWidth.

Comment: Jitamaro, I do not quite understand your comment here. I changed the `columnWidth`value for `gutterWidth`.

Comment: It means that masonry arrange the items vertical and not horizontal and its maybe not possible to have the same width of the container with the same width of the header.

Comment: Play with the browser window size, you will better understand what I mean.

Comment: The content get resized, that is exactly what I wrote, when you change the vertical width masonry will arrange the bricks in vertical. you must give the parent container a fixed width and the columnwidth is a multiple of the container width.